# Why there are fields which are visible only when debug mode is activate?

Tags: odoo

Why there is some fields which are visible only when debug mode is activate (like remaining_leaves ) ? and if i want to create a field like that how can'I do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done with a "special" access group whose xml ID is `base.group_no_one`.

So if you need a field with this behaviour:

```xml
<field name="my_field" groups="base.group_no_one" />
```